# Handling UnobservedTaskException

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, continuations

I've an application that is configured to catch any unobserved task exceptions having ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true" in app.config.

I've a library class(Class1) that needs to start an async task in it's constructor, but in some scenarios that throws exception and I get into UnobservedTaskException error when the instance of Class1 gets disposed(since that task is never awaited).

I fixed that by attaching a ContinueWith on the task in the constructor and handling the exception(by accessing Exception property of the task) with TaskContinuationOptions set to OnlyOnFaulted and this worked perfectly.

Now the issue I have is that this async task(that I initialize in constructor) is also being awaited in methods of this class as a validation check to ensure that task is completed before proceeding to rest of the code in the method. If I had called this method after instantiating my class(Class1) and if it throws an error, the ContinueWith that I had attached gets executed and the exception is handled. I don't want this behavior. I want it to throw the exception if it results in an error when being awaited inside a method.

I only want the unobservedtaskexceptions to be handled for this case only(not for the entire application) - which is the case when the Class1 is initialized and no methods called and if the task throws an exception, I handle it in ContinueWith. I don't want the code in ContinueWith to be executed when this task is being awaited inside a method and if that throws.

Here is the code that will provide more clarity. Please let me know if there is a way for me to achieve this.

Program.cs

```
using (Class1 c = new Class1())
{
       c.ValidateInitializeAsync().Wait(); // I want this to throw. Only if this line is commented, I want the exception to be handled.
}

// The application needs to be run in Release mode in order for GC to dispose c and enter into the scenario I want
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
 }
```

Class1.cs

```
class Class1 : IDisposable
{
    public Task initializeTask;

    public Class1()
    {

        this.initializeTask = TaskHelper.InlineIfPossible(() => RunTask()).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception handled, {0}", t.Exception.HResult));

        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }

    public async Task ValidateInitializeAsync()
    {
        await this.initializeTask;
    }
    public async Task RunTask()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running task...");
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
            throw new InvalidOperationException("exception occured");
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class1 disposed.");
    }
}

static class TaskHelper
{
    static public Task InlineIfPossible(Func<Task> function)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
        {
            return function();
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.Run(function);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't possible. Think about it as time moves forward: when `RunTask` completes with an exception, the code must know **right then** whether to handle that exception. It can't look into the future and determine whether it **will be** handled by an `await` further up the stack.

I recommend using an [async factory pattern](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html), so that any initialization exceptions are propagated immediately, before the calling code even gets the instance.